# magento product count per attribute 'country_of_manufacture'

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

i need to count/group/select product on base of attribute 'country_of_manufacture'. 
like this

> India => 10, Shrilanka => 5,

how can  achieve it in magento?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    $collection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('total_country_of_manufacture',"COUNT({{entity_id}})",'entity_id')
        ->groupByAttribute('country_of_manufacture');
```

for count

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->groupByAttribute('country_of_manufacture')
                ->addExpressionAttributeToSelect("cnt_product",'COUNT({{entity_id}})', 'entity_id')
                ->load();
```

Comment: this query just show me only those country which has product.

Comment: you can use `count($collection)`

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check if it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
count($collection)
```

you can try

```
$collection->getSelect()->count();
```